# How to detect white screen in electron.BrowserWindow when network is offline

Tags: electron

I'm sorry. I do not speak English well.

I am developing the Electron project.
This desktop app runs to load external sites.
However, if the app refreshes when the network is offline,
A white screen is displayed.
However, instead of did-failed-load, the did-finish-load event is fired.
It is impossible to check whether the page is loaded.
Is there any good way to check if the white screen is loaded?

```
const win = new BrowserWindow();
win.loadUrl('https://.../app');

win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  // did finish load
});

win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
  // did fail load
});

globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+R', () => win.webContents.reload());
```